# Is it possible to (bypass childs own relationship) use parents relationship result instead childs itself?

Tags: laravel

I have a `ProductParent` and `ProductChild` model with the simple parent/child relations below. Besides that the parent model has a `modifiers()` relation. I want to call the parent's `modifiers()` relation for the child.

```
// ProductParent
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductChild::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function modifiers()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Modifier::class, 'modifiable', 'modifiables', 'modifiable_id', 'modifier_id');
}

// ProductChild
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ProductParent::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

I can call the parent like:

```
// ProductChild
public function parentsModifiers(){
    return $this->parent();
}
```

I get the parent's data but I want to imitiate when the child modifiers are called directly calling the parents relation.

How can I directly (eager loadable way) get the parent's `modifiers()` relation from the child ?

Comment: Not tested it at all and only speculating but maybe `$this->parent()->modifiers()->union($this->modifiers())` might work

Comment: I tried it out didnt work.got this strange error: `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/RelationNotFoundException with message 'Call to undefined relationship [modifiers] on model [App/Models/ProductChild]'`. the modifiers relation does exist for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to simply use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) and then [append](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) it to the model so that every json returns the `modifiers` (that will be taken from the parent) accessor automatically.

I think this will have a tiny performance impact but because I am calling limited records using [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#pagination) for the products I guess it is tolerable.

```
// ProductParent
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductChild::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function modifiers()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Modifier::class, 'modifiable', 'modifiables', 'modifiable_id', 'modifier_id');
}

// ProductChild
protected $appends = ['errors', 'modifiers'];

...

public function getModifiersAttribute(){
    return $this->parent->title;
}
```

If there are better ways to go or any other toughts on this I would appreciate it.